# Clicking a button with WATIR WebDriver

Tags: custom-controls, watir, watir-webdriver

I have been struggling with this all morning and was hoping to get some assistance.
I have this button on a webpage that pulls up a control panel that lets the user select which widgets to display.   I'm trying to get this to fire using watir webdriver and firefox 9.0 but having no luck at all.   I'm able to login to the site, get to the page that contains the button but just can't click the 'CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES' button.

```
<div class="personalizationButton">
  <span class="personalizationStatus"></span>
  &nbsp;
  <b class="widgetPanelLink neo-button button-white">
    <span>CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES</span>
  </b>
</div>`
```

I've been concentrating on using div class 'personalizationButton' but perhaps I need to point to that 'b class'?  Just not sure how to format it.  Here are some examples of what I have tried

```
$browser.div(:class, 'personalizationButton').when_present.click 
$browser.button(:text => 'CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES').click 
$browser.button(:div => 'personalizationButton').click
```

etc, etc... just not sure I'm getting the format right. I watch it get to the page, I see the 'CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES' button on the page, but it never clicks it. Usually I get an error like this depending on which version was used:

```
unable to locate element, using {:text=>"CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES", :tag_name=>"button"}
```

This is the version I think should work, When I try it I get no errors but see nothing happen in the browser either:

```
$browser.div(:class => "personalizationButton").click
```

Comment: Derek, can you please post what you've tried so far with Watir?  Thanks for providing the HTML up front (do you have a link?).  Also, can you please post the error - is it not locating the div, or not clicking what you want, etc?

Comment: `$browser.div(:class, 'personalizationButton').when_present.click` `$browser.button(:text => 'CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES').click` `$browser.button(:div => 'personalizationButton').click` etc, etc...  just not sure I'm getting the format right.   I watch it get to the page, I see the 'CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES' button on the page, but it never clicks it.   Usually I get an error like this depending on which version was used:  `unable to locate element, using {:text=>"CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES", :tag_name=>"button"}`

Comment: This is the version I think should work, but I get no errors and see nothing happen in the browser either:   `$browser.div(:class => "personalizationButton").click`

Comment: This is all I see in IRB when I try it:   `>> $browser.div(:class => "personalizationButton").click
=> []
`

Comment: what you likely have there is a div or span that is made to look like a button, likely via a backround image controlled via CSS and the style of the div/span. In this situation unless you can have a developer tell you what element is reacting to a click, you just have to try clicking on what is there.  a B tag by the way is just boldface, it's a text formatting tag, and not generally clickable.

Comment: I edited the question (you should be able to do that yourself Derek since it's your question) to make the HTML structure more apparent and include the code provided in comments above.   Note that the 'button' code would fail since there is no  element in your HTML that qualifies as a button (either an input of type button, or a link using an image)  which is why you get the not found error for those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not seeing anything inherently clickable (with output) in the HTML.  With the IRB output, it shows that it is finding the div, but there is no action when clicking it.  The `<b>` element is just the "bold" style, so we shouldn't need to try that.

If you can access the span with text CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES, that should be your button.

```
$browser.span(:text => "CHOOSE YOUR FEATURES").click
```

Comment: EUREKA,   had no idea I could do something like that.  That did it!  Thanks so much!

Comment: If you don't mind one more pointer related to the same situation...  On the choose your features page, there are several options that can be turned on or off.  All of them are identified via span tags with ADD.  So I need to be able to click on ADD but for specific ones. `<div class="add-widget-widget add-widget-widget-QuotesDetails">  <div class="add-widget-registryId">QuotesDetails</div> . . . . . . .<span>ADD</span></b>     </div> </div>`   so i think i have to use the div class and the span class in the same click action?

Comment: I got it... Using your earlier example, I was able to come up with this... again, Fantastic!   Starting to get the hang of this.   `$browser.div(:class =>'add-widget-widget add-widget-widget-QuotesDetails').span(:text => 'ADD').click`

Comment: Although it's a bit fragile, you can also use the "index" of an element to find a specific one (the first will be 0).  You can also use combinations of locators if you need to:  @browser.span(:text => "ADD", :index => 2).click.  The way that you've done it using the parent DIV element is best, however!

Answer (score 0):

. . i have tried doing the same thing with godaddy.com buy it did work.
on the main page there is a button labeled "Buy Now" using the code below
brow.div(:class => 'gdhp-domain-link gdhp-rounded-corners').span(:text => 'Buy Now').click
I was

Comment: Trying to continue with a similar but different issue, in an ANSWER to an earlier question is very confusing and not likely to ever get a response.  *Please start a new question, post relevant html and the watir code you have tried, any errors etc.* You can reference back to this question (use the 'link' link under the question, copy the link provided and paste into your new question) if you feel that helps explain really needed.  (but in general it's better just to ask a new question that stands on its own)